# How can I access a variable in WCF in a static nature where the instance is not shared across calls?

Tags: wcf

I have a value that I want to be able to access within a WCF service in a static nature, so that I do not have to pass an instance of an object throughout the different methods, but I do not want each call to the service to share the instance, only to have the value available within a single call.  If I actually use a "static" variable to store the value, it ends up being shared across multiple calls to the service, which is not the behavior that I am after.  The same thing happened when I stored the value in AppDomain.  My service is defined as PerCall and is hosted in IIS, if that makes any difference to the solution.  Thank you.

Comment: I just discovered the InstanceContext.GetServiceInstance method.  It looks like I can expose a property off of my service class and just access that using GetServiceInstance, which will guarantee that I have a separate context per call.  However, is there a natural container on InstanceContext that I can store things, so that I do not have to create my own?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer over on another forum.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/aa27f0a3-2b9f-44cb-bd5c-9020c8502883/how-can-i-access-a-variable-in-wcf-in-a-static-nature-where-the-instance-is-not-shared-across-calls?forum=wcf